# What should I do to reduce run time of my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

This is a URI online judge problem (problem no: 1973).

> After buying many adjacent farms at the west region of Santa Catarina, the Star family built a single road which passes by all farms in sequence. The first farm of the sequence was named Star 1, the second Star 2, and so on. However, the brother who lives in Star 1 has got mad and decided to make a Star Trek in order to steal sheep from the proprieties of his siblings. But he is definitely crazy. When passes by the farm Star i, he steals only one sheep (if there is any) from that farm and moves on either to Star i + 1 or Star i - 1, depending on whether the number of sheep in Star i was, respectively, odd or even. If there is not the Star to which he wants to go, he halts his trek. The mad brother starts his Star Trek in Star 1, stealing a sheep from his own farm.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first input line consists of a single integer N (1 ≤ N ≤ 106), which represents the number of Stars. The second input line consists of N integers, such that the ith integer, Xi (1 ≤ Xi ≤ 106), represents the initial number of sheep in Star i.
>
> **Output**
>
> Output a line containing two integers, so that the first represents the number of Stars attacked by the mad brother and the second represents the total number of non-stolen sheep.
>
> [image: input and output samples]

I have solved the problem and also give the desired output, but every time I submitted it it says time limit exceeded.

```
#1st solution:
num_star = int(input())
sheep = list(map(int, input().split()))
star = set()
index = 0

while index != num_star:
    if sheep[index] == 0:
        break
    elif sheep[index] % 2 == 1:
        star.add(index)
        sheep[index] -= 1
        index += 1
    else:
        star.add(index)
        sheep[index] -= 1
        index -= 1
        if index == -1:
            break

print(len(star), sum(sheep))

#2nd solution
n = int(input())
x = list(map(int, input().split()))
i = 0
farm_visited = 0
while i in range(n):
    if x[i] == 0:
        if i >= farm_visited: farm_visited = i+1
        break
    elif (x[i]) % 2 == 1:
        if i >= farm_visited: farm_visited = i + 1
        x[i] -= 1
        i += 1
    else:
        if i >= farm_visited: farm_visited = i + 1
        x[i] -= 1
        i -= 1
print(farm_visited, sum(x))
```

Comment: It seems that your code is too slow. There may be more efficient implementations. You should try asking the question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hint: you don't need to repeat all the tasks done by the mad Star. Notice that he goes forward until he hits an even number, then he goes backward all the way to the beginning (or the farm initally having 1 sheep), since by stealing a single sheep from an odd number he left only even numbers behing him. So it is enough to find the first even number in the list… and then it is just simple math.

Comment: @Błotosmętek then what should be the equation of non-stolen sheep and what if he left a zero behind him after stealing (for even case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't read below if you want to solve it on your own.

```
def madstar(s): # s is the list
    if all(e % 2 for e in s): # all Stars with odd numbers
        return (len(s), sum(s)-len(s)) # just one sheep stolen from each Star
    for i,e in enumerate(s):
        if e % 2 == 0: # even number found
            return (i+1, # Stars are numbered from 0, so i==0 -> 1 Star visited etc.
                    sum(s) - ( # stolen sheep
                           2*(i+1) # two for every visited Star 
                           - s[:i].count(1) # except visited Stars with initially only 1 sheep
                           - (1 if e>0 else 2) # and the final one, where it is either 0 or 1, but never 2
            ))

for test_list in [[1,3,5,7,11,13,17,19],
                  [1,3,5,7,11,13,16,19],
                  [1],
                  [3,0,2],
                  [0],
                  [2]]:
    print(test_list, '->', madstar(test_list))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Błotosmętek. After seeing your solution I think, I need to learn more about Python3 such as all, enumerate. can you suggest some tips and courses for me to learn more about python which will help for the long run. I just have completed the basic of Python3.

Answer (score 0):

Find here another (maybe easier?) implementation.
Don't read below if you want to solve it on your own!

```
num_star = int(input())
def print_solution(stars_list):
  sheep_taken_when_go = 0
  sheep_taken_when_return = 0
  visited_stars_count = 0
  total_sheep = sum(stars_list)
  for sheep_in_current_star in stars_list:
    visited_stars_count+=1
    sheep_taken_when_go += 1 if sheep_in_current_star>0 else 0 #take one sheep if available
    if sheep_in_current_star%2==0:
      print(visited_stars_count,total_sheep-sheep_taken_when_go-sheep_taken_when_return)
      return
    sheep_taken_when_return += 1 if sheep_in_current_star>1 else 0 #if we ever return, take another sheep if available
  print(visited_stars_count,total_sheep-sheep_taken_when_go)

print_solution(list(map(int, input().split())))
```

Comment: That was convenient

Answer (score 0):

**solved**
*thanks @Błotosmętek and thanks everyone.*

```
def thief(stars, sheep):
    pos_even = 0
    for i in range(stars):
        if sheep[i] % 2 == 0:
            pos_even = i + 1
            last_even_value = sheep[i]
            break
    if pos_even:
        print(pos_even, (sum(sheep) - (pos_even * 2 - sheep[:i].count(1) - (1 if last_even_value > 0 else 2))))
    else:
        print(stars, (sum(sheep) - stars))
num_star = int(input())
s = list(map(int, input().split()[:num_star]))
thief(num_star, s)
```